# How to open WebView in android by clicking ImageButton?

Tags: android

```
    android:layout_width="368dp"
    android:layout_height="495dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="8dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp">

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:visibility="invisible" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imgButton"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="140dp"
        android:onClick="loadUrl"
        android:src="@drawable/img"
        android:contentDescription="@null"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

How can I open a website in my app by clicking a ImageButton or ImageView without open any browser?

Answer (score 0):

```
        public void loadUrl(View view) {
                View rootView = view.getParent();
                wv =(WebView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.web_page);
                wv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                wv.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());

                wv.loadUrl("http\\and.so.on");
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public void loadUrl(View view) {
    webView = findViewById(R.id.webView);
    webView.getSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.setChromeClient(new ChromeClient());
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    webView.loadUrl("Whatever you want to load");
}
```